# Vue.js pagination calculation not working as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to implement pagination for the first time in my vue app. I have some data that will be loaded from dexie.js using this code:

```
        async viewCustomers() {
            db.customers.each( (item) => {
                this.customersList.push(item)
            })
        },
```

I'm populating the `customersList` array inside the `.each` method of dexie.js. This will output the data inside an html5 bootstrap table that for now will display all the entries of the table.
I'm reading various questions about javascript pagination and I've done some serach. As I understand I need to set a limit for the entries of a single table page and the start page. I've done this in this way inside the `data()` method of my vue component:

```
    data() {
        return {
            customersList: [],
            currentPage: 1,
            perPage: 5,
        }
    },
```

Now, I'm trying to get the lenght of the `customersList` array afer that it's populated with the data but I will get always 0, this means that if I try to do something like this `Math.ceil( this.customersList.length / this.perPage )` it will not give the expected result and I get a 0.

I don't know if I'm trying to implement the pagination in a wrong way but any help will be appreciated. I want to use the bootstrap 4 pagination, but for now this is not relevant, I need to make it working first.

**UPDATE**

I've done some modification to the code, I've cahnged the `.each` method of dexie.js with the `.toArray` method. Now I'm able to get the array length and I get the result from the `Math.ceil()` operation. Now from this point, I need to assign the right amount of data to each page and calculate the numbers of pages. Here I need some help.

```
        async viewCustomers() {
            let today = new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleDateString();
            // db.customers.each( (item) => {
            //     console.log(today)
            //     if(item.expirationDate === today){
            //         console.log('Automatically removed user:'+ item.id)
            //         this.deleteCustomer(item.id);
            //     }
            //     this.customersList.push(item)
            // })
            db.customers.toArray( (items) => {
                console.log(items)
                this.customersList = items
                console.log(this.customersList.length)
                console.log(this.paginateCustomersData( this.customersList.length, this.perPage ))
            })
        },
        paginateCustomersData(dataLength, itemsPerPage) {
            return Math.ceil(dataLength / itemsPerPage)  
        },
        nextPage() {
            this.currentPage++;
        },
        prevPage() {
            this.currentPage--;
        },
```

**UPDATE 2:**

After some headche and after reading a similar question here on SO I've implemented the pagination with this reworked code:

```
    viewCustomers() {
            db.customers.toArray( (items) => {
                console.log(items)
                this.rawData = items
                this.customersList = this.paginateCustomersData(items ,this.rawData.length, this.perPage)
            })
        },
        paginateCustomersData(data, dataLength, itemsPerPage) {
            this.customersList = data.slice((this.currentPage - 1) * this.perPage, this.currentPage * this.perPage)
            return this.customersList
        },
        nextPage() {
            this.currentPage++;

            console.log(this.rawData.length, this.currentPage)
            this.paginateCustomersData(this.rawData, this.customersList.length, this.perPage)
        },
        prevPage() {
            this.currentPage--;
            console.log(this.rawData.length, this.currentPage)
            this.paginateCustomersData(this.rawData, this.customersList.length, this.perPage)
        },
```

I need only to prevent that the two buttons I've created to change the current page can display an empty table because no record is available and all data are paginated. Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 4 not vue bootstrap. For the `customersList`, I've already published how I get the data from dexie.

Comment: if you're using the  Vue developer tool could please check whether after the request the customerList is populated?  if not then check your async function. you need to await the results before you push to the customerList.

Comment: I've already specified in the question that the `customersList` array is populated. It will be an array of objects because the `.each` function of dexie will return objects in a table. I didn't tested the `.toArray` method of dexie, but my problem is implementing pagination

Comment: Check if there is an error `can not find customersList of undefined` in your console.

Comment: nope, no error is logged.

Comment: are you getting the length of the customerList array as a computed property?